# Learning vocabulary is a journey wihout destination, but exist ways to accelerate?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary, definition, learning-methods

Is a hassle to learn vocabulary, I'm not saying is the devil and needs to be avoided, it's worth-while but I have been learning for the past year and I feel it consume a lot of my time and energy that could be invested in other important things, I will explain my way of learning vocabulary if you find a flawed or a better distinct way to do it please let us know! Not only you help me, but also future learners with the same problem, here is my "system to learn":

**Resources:**
Consume information in the targeted foreign language you want to learn could be text, audios, etc.

**Types of Process:**
If I do not understand a word or phrase, I can do the following:

*Process Void:*

1. Ignore it

*Process Lazy:*

1. Trying to know vaguely the meaning by only inferring with the context only.
2. Not confirming it in the dictionary.

*Process Fast:*

1. Directly search the meaning, or ask, not trying to infer the meaning, just going and look up the word.
2. Repeat in my own words the definition and type it in a personal lexicon with the word obviously.

*The Best Process:*

1. Trying to know vaguely the meaning by inferring with the context only.
2. Confirm with the dictionary.
3. Correct if is needed
4. Repeat in my own words the definition and type it in a personal lexicon with the word obviously

It sounds easy the best process, right? Not really, I'm trying to do the "The Best Process", the challenge is, the Dictionary is like an ocean, the myriad of organisms living there, you can have the intentions to hunt the seastar, but when you find a seahorse you spend time with it, then suddenly you found the clownfish, and keep going until you don't find anymore.

With words happens the same, I'm looking only at one word in the dictionary and I find often a myriad of definitions, and on the internet is a myriad of webpages and then various of definitions, when I see the definition, I find in the definition itself other unknown words, and when I search for their respective definition sometimes are defined with the previously same unknown word that led me to search the word, force me to dip into new resources, new dictionaries, new webpages, etc. Yes, I learn Vocabulary this way, others do, but I feel the process is a hassle to hell, is affecting me, with my time, my energy, and ultimately my life needs to exist better productive ways, I wait with craving your helpful systems or tips to learn vocabulary.